# Add comments with FPDF

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

Is there a way to add a "comment" to a PDF generated with PHP and FPDF which is displayed on the screen but doesn't get printed on paper when printing the PDF document?

Answer (score 0):

There are some FPDF functions that could be used for that:

`SetAuthor`, `SetCreator`, `SetKeywords`, `SetSubject`

These values cannot be printed on paper and they can be read with every PDF-reader (show document properties) and also with PHP...

```
$pdf = Zend_Pdf::load($pdf_file_path);

echo $pdf->properties['Title'];
echo $pdf->properties['Author'];
```